# removing javascript and CSS from Search pages

Tags: magento-1.9

i have been removing java scripts and CSS files which are not needed on certain pages I have managed to do this for my homepages, my category pages and my product pages but i am struggling to do it for my search page. This is the code i am adding:

```
    <catalogsearch_result_index>
    <reference name="head">
            <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><stylesheet>CSS file path</stylesheet></action>
    </reference>
```

I assume i need to change catalogsearch_result_index but i am not sure what to

Comment: Well `catalogsearch_result_index` is the correct layout handle, unless you're talking about the advanced search page.

Comment: When i inspect the page that is what appears as the class of the body

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<catalogsearch_result_index translate="label">
    <reference name="head">
        <action method="removeItem"><type>js</type><name>yourjsname.js</name></action> <!-- For a JS in the js folder -->
        <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>yourjsname.js</name></action> <!-- For a JS in the skin folder -->
        <action method="removeItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>yourcssname.css</name></action> <!-- For CSS in the skin folder -->
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>
```

add this in the local.xml and clear cache.